# Расстановка скобок в коде при помощи стека, помогите найти ошибку в синтаксисе, си

Tags: c, структуры-данных, стек

Программа проверяет правильно ли расставлены скобки в коде.

Сделал два стека в одном хранятся элементы т.е. скобки, в другом номера этих элементов. В случае правильной расстановки скобок должен быть вывод надписи Success, в случае не правильной расстановки скобок программа должна вывести номер по порядку первой закрывающей скобки для которой нет соответствующей открывающей, т.е. той которая лежит на верху стека.

Голову уже сломал, понять не могу что не так сделал.

Помогите сделать правильно.

Тесты для проверки программы:

[]           - Success

{}[]         - Success

[()]         - Success

(())         - Success

{[]}()       - Success

({([])}) - Success

foo(bar);    - Success

{            - 1

{[}          - 3

()[]}        - 5

[]([]        - 3

{{[()]]      - 7

{{{[][][]    - 3

foo(bar[i);  - 10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NMAX 100000

// СТЭК хранилища
typedef struct stackElm {
    char *elem; // хранилище
    size_t topE; // индекс элемента, находящегося в вершине стека.
} stackElm;
// СТЕК счётчика
typedef struct stackNum {
    int num[NMAX]; // счётчик
    size_t topN; // индекс элемента, находящегося в вершине стека.
} stackNum;

// 1 Инициализация стека хранилища.
void initE(stackElm *stkE);
// 2 Инициализация стека счётчика
void initN(stackNum *stkN);
// 3 Помещение элемента в стек хранилища
void pushE(stackElm *stkE, char e);
// 4 Помещение элемента в стек счётчика
void pushN(stackNum *stk, int n);
// 5 Удаление элемента из стек хранилища
char popE(stackElm *stkE);
// 6 Удаление элемента из стека счётчика
int popN(stackNum *stkN);
// 7 Извлечение вершины стека хранилища
int stkTopE(stackElm *stkE);
// 8 Извлечение вершины стека счётчика
int stkTopN(stackNum *stkN);
// 9 Получение верхнего элемента стека хранилища без его удаления 
int gettopE(stackElm *stkE);
// 10 Получение верхнего элемента стека счётчика без его удаления
int gettopN(stackNum *stkN);
// 11 Определение пустоты стека хранилища
int isemptyE(stackElm *stkE);
// 12 Определение пустоты стека счётчика
int isemptyN(stackNum *stkN);

void main(void) {
    system("cls");
    stackElm *stkE;
    stackNum *stkN;
    char elm[NMAX];
    int num, error = 0;
    stkE = (stackElm*)malloc(sizeof(stackElm));
    stkN = (stackNum*)malloc(sizeof(stackNum));
    initE(stkE);
    initN(stkN);
    scanf("%s", elm);
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(elm) + 1; i < n; i++) {
        num = i + 1;
        if(elm[i] == '(' || elm[i] == '[' || elm[i] == '{') {
            pushE(stkE, elm[i]);
            pushN(stkN, num);
            printf("push1 %c Num %d Elm %s\n", elm[i], stkN->num, stkE->elem);
        }
        else if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) != '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) != '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) != '{')) {
            error = stkTopN(stkN);
            pushE(stkE, elm[i]);
            pushN(stkN, num);
            printf("push2 %c Num %d Elm %s\n", elm[i], stkN->num, stkE->elem);
        }
        else if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) == '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) == '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) == '{')) {
            popE(stkE);
            popN(stkN);
            printf("pop  %c Num %d Elm %s\n", elm[i], stkN->num, stkE->elem);
        }
    }
    if(isemptyE(stkE) == 1)
        printf("Success\n");
    else
        printf("%d", stkTopN(stkN));
}
// 1 Инициализация стека хранилища
void initE(stackElm *stkE) {
    stkE->topE = 0;
}
// 2 Инициализация стека счётчика
void initN(stackNum *stkN) {
    stkN->topN = 0;
}
// 3 Помещение элемента в стек хранилища
void pushE(stackElm *stkE, char e) {
    if(stkE->topE < NMAX) {
        stkE->elem[stkE->topE] = e;
        stkE->topE++;
    } 
    else
        printf("Error: stack overflow %d !\n", stkE->topE);
}
// 4 Помещение элемента в стек счётчика
void pushN(stackNum *stkN, int n) {
    if(stkN->topN < NMAX) {
        stkN->num[stkN->topN] = n;
        stkN->topN++;
    } 
    else
        printf("Error: stack overflow %d !\n", stkN->topN);
}
// 5 Удаление элемента из стека хранилища
char popE(stackElm *stkE) {
    char elem;
    if((stkE->topE) > 0) {
        stkE->topE--;
        elem = stkE->elem[stkE->topE];
        return elem;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
// 6 Удаление элемента из стека счётчика
int popN(stackNum *stkN) {
    int n;
    if((stkN->topN) > 0) {
        stkN->topN--;
        n = stkN->num[stkN->topN];
        return n;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
// 7 Извлечение вершины стека хранилища
int stkTopE(stackElm *stkE) {
    if((stkE->topE) > 0)
        return stkE->elem[stkE->topE--];
    else
        return 0;
}
// 8 Извлечение вершины стека счётчика
int stkTopN(stackNum *stkN) {
    if((stkN->topN) > 0)
        return stkN->num[stkN->topN--];
    else
        return 0;
}
// 9 Получение верхнего элемента стека хранилища без его удаления 
int gettopE(stackElm *stkE) {
    return stkE->topE;
}
// 10 Получение верхнего элемента стека счётчика без его удаления
int gettopN(stackNum *stkN) {
    return stkN->topN;
}
// 11 Определение пустоты стека хранилища
int isemptyE(stackElm *stkE) {
    if((stkE->topE) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
// 12 Определение пустоты стека счётчика
int isemptyN(stackNum *stkN) {
    if((stkN->topN) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в синтаксисе структуры, у одной структуры указатель у другой, массив.
Сейчас всё работает хорошо, все тесты проходят, однако сайт степика всё ровно её не принимает. не знаю почему...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NMAX 100000

// СТЭК хранилища
typedef struct stackElm {
    char elem[NMAX]; // хранилище
    size_t topE; // индекс элемента, находящегося в вершине стека.
} stackElm;
// СТЕК счётчика
typedef struct stackNum {
    int num[NMAX]; // счётчик
    size_t topN; // индекс элемента, находящегося в вершине стека.
} stackNum;

// 1 Инициализация стека хранилища.
void initE(stackElm *stkE);
// 2 Инициализация стека счётчика
void initN(stackNum *stkN);
// 3 Помещение элемента в стек хранилища
void pushE(stackElm *stkE, char e);
// 4 Помещение элемента в стек счётчика
void pushN(stackNum *stk, int num);
// 5 Удаление элемента из стек хранилища
char popE(stackElm *stkE);
// 6 Удаление элемента из стека счётчика
int popN(stackNum *stkN);
// 7 Извлечение вершины стека хранилища
int stkTopE(stackElm *stkE);
// 8 Извлечение вершины стека счётчика
int stkTopN(stackNum *stkN);
// 9 Получение верхнего элемента стека хранилища без его удаления 
int gettopE(stackElm *stkE);
// 10 Получение верхнего элемента стека счётчика без его удаления
int gettopN(stackNum *stkN);
// 11 Определение пустоты стека хранилища
int isemptyE(stackElm *stkE);
// 12 Определение пустоты стека счётчика
int isemptyN(stackNum *stkN);

/*
[] - Success
{}[] - Success
[()] - Success
(()) - Success
{[]}() - Success
({([])}) - Success
foo(bar); - Success
{ - 1
{[} - 3
()[]} - 5
[]([] - 3
{{[()]] - 7
{{{[][][] - 3
foo(bar[i); - 10
*/

void main(void) {
    system("cls");
    stackElm *stkE;
    stackNum *stkN;
    char elm[NMAX];
    stkE = (stackElm*)malloc(sizeof(stackElm));
    stkN = (stackNum*)malloc(sizeof(stackNum));
    initE(stkE);
    initN(stkN);
    scanf("%s", elm);
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(elm) + 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(elm[i] == '(' || elm[i] == '[' || elm[i] == '{') {
            pushE(stkE, elm[i]);
            pushN(stkN, i + 1);
        }
        else if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) != '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) != '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) != '{')) {
            pushE(stkE, elm[i]);
            pushN(stkN, i + 1);
        }
        else if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) == '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) == '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) == '{')) {
            popE(stkE);
            popN(stkN);
        }
    }
    if(isemptyE(stkE) == 1)
        printf("Success\n");
    else
        printf("%i\n", stkTopN(stkN));
    free(stkE);
    free(stkN);
}
// 1 Инициализация стека хранилища
void initE(stackElm *stkE) {
    stkE->topE = 0;
}
// 2 Инициализация стека счётчика
void initN(stackNum *stkN) {
    stkN->num[0] = 0;
    stkN->topN = 0;
}
// 3 Помещение элемента в стек хранилища
void pushE(stackElm *stkE, char e) {
    if(stkE->topE < NMAX) {
        stkE->elem[stkE->topE] = e;
        stkE->topE++;
    } 
    else
        printf("Error: stack overflow %d !\n", stkE->topE);
}
// 4 Помещение элемента в стек счётчика
void pushN(stackNum *stkN, int num) {
    if(stkN->topN < NMAX) {
        stkN->num[stkN->topN] = num;
        stkN->topN++;
    } 
    else
        printf("Error: stack overflow %d !\n", stkN->topN);
}
// 5 Удаление элемента из стека хранилища
char popE(stackElm *stkE) {
    char elem;
    if((stkE->topE) > 0) {
        stkE->topE--;
        elem = stkE->elem[stkE->topE];
        return elem;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
// 6 Удаление элемента из стека счётчика
int popN(stackNum *stkN) {
    int n;
    if((stkN->topN) > 0) {
        stkN->topN--;
        n = stkN->num[stkN->topN];
        return n;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
// 7 Извлечение вершины стека хранилища
int stkTopE(stackElm *stkE) {
    if((stkE->topE) > 0)
        return stkE->elem[stkE->topE - 1];
    else
        return 0;
}
// 8 Извлечение вершины стека счётчика
int stkTopN(stackNum *stkN) {
    if((stkN->topN) > 0)
        return stkN->num[stkN->topN - 1];
    else
        return 0;
}
// 9 Получение верхнего элемента стека хранилища без его удаления 
int gettopE(stackElm *stkE) {
    return stkE->topE;
}
// 10 Получение верхнего элемента стека счётчика без его удаления
int gettopN(stackNum *stkN) {
    return stkN->topN;
}
// 11 Определение пустоты стека хранилища
int isemptyE(stackElm *stkE) {
    if((stkE->topE) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
// 12 Определение пустоты стека счётчика
int isemptyN(stackNum *stkN) {
    if((stkN->topN) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При правильном закрытии скобки два раза вызывается **stkTopE** . Можно было бы назвать этот метод не **Top** а **Pop**. Нужно спрятать этот метод, чтобы не было дважды.

```
        if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) != '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) != '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) != '{')) { ...
        }
        else if
            ((elm[i] == ')' && stkTopE(stkE) == '(') ||
             (elm[i] == ']' && stkTopE(stkE) == '[') ||
             (elm[i] == '}' && stkTopE(stkE) == '{')) { ...
```